# Problems installing QT online installer in Rhel 7

Tags: rhel, qt

Relatively new to linux.

I'm trying to run the qt online installer on a rhel 7 machine.
Version info:

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# hostnamectl 
   Static hostname: localhost.localdomain
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
        Machine ID: 984cef87c98f48be9355b28d1e22aa17
           Boot ID: 36ec38de9f964dcfa7242c6c7da77e11
  Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.9:GA:workstation
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.102.1.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

When running the application, I get this error:

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# ./qt-unified-linux-x64-4.6.1-online.run
./qt-unified-linux-x64-4.6.1-online.run: error while loading shared libraries: libxcb-icccm.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried installing `libxcb-icccm.so.4`:

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# yum install libxcb-icccm.so.4
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Package xcb-util-wm-0.4.1-5.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@localhost Downloads]#
```

ldd reveals:

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# ldd qt-unified-linux-x64-4.6.1-online.run 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc801c5000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fc3c7a16000)
    libbz2.so.1 => /lib64/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007fc3c7806000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fc3c75e0000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007fc3c739e000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fc3c70df000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007fc3c6e8f000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007fc3c6c74000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007fc3c6a72000)
    libxcb-icccm.so.4 => not found
    libxcb-image.so.0 => not found
```

I'm assuming I need to associate the installed package with the package name that the qt-online installer is looking for, but I don't know how to do this, or if that's even a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ldd qt-unified-linux-x64-4.6.1-online.run` shows that all of the libraries that are found are under `/lib64`. Your package system says that the `i686` version of `xcb-util-wm` is installed. This does provide libxcb-iccm.so.4, but it is under `/lib` or `/usr/lib`, the difference being 32 bit vs 64 bit versions. Try installing `xcb-util-wm-0.4.1-5.el7.x86_64` which provides `/usr/lib64/libxcb-icccm.so.4` (the 64 bit version) of the library. It also looks like you will need to install `xcb-util-image.x86_64` in order to install `libxcb-image.so.0` which your `ldd` listed as not found.

tl;dr `yum install xcb-util-wm.x86_64 xcb-util-image.x86_64` to install the 64 bit versions of the missing libraries